# this.on event Emitter on react-native is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-native, dom-events

I'm trying to emit and listen on a Event. The emit is working but when I try to listen the application breaks. Can anybody give me a hand on this?

This is the code:

```
export class EmitEvents extends EventEmitter {
  constructor () {
    super()
    this.valid_devices_list = {}
  }

  _discover() {
    this.emit('found');
    this.on('found', function () {
      console.log('Got it!')
    })

  }
}
```

When I execute it this.on give me an error:

> this.on is not a function

Any help on this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The class EventEmitter doesn't have method on https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/Libraries/EventEmitter/EventEmitter.js .

You must use addListener instead.